# Why are these two elements vertically offset although display:flex is used?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want the text and the icon both perfectly vertically centered like this:

[image: Screen correct]

That's why I used `display:flex` with `align-items:center` but what I get is this:

[image: Screen fail]

### Code

Note: I am using React, so please mind the inline-styles :-)

```
<div style="background-color:#999;position:fixed;width:100%;height:52px;box-shadow:0 -12px 27px #999;display:flex;align-items:center">
   <div style="flex:1;height:24px;margin-left:20px">
      <div style="display:inline-block;width:24px;height:24px;border: 1px solid green;">
         <img style="width:100%;height:100%;border:0" src="https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/63/33/38/240_F_63333813_qO48nGh5uFZ0EVkCYS3ZehhrR10dWg4D.jpg" alt="Logo">
      </div>
      <h1 style="display:inline-block;margin:0;text-transform:uppercase;font-family:Raleway, serif;font-weight:900;font-size:18px;height:24px;border: 1px solid red;">MyLogo</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

### Pen

https://codepen.io/valnub/pen/XzxOvY

What's wrong? I don't get it :-( Please help me, oh mighty flexbox css masters!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the outer container to display: flex, but not the inner container. Adding display: flex to that should fix your issue:

```
<div style="background-color:#999;position:fixed;width:100%;height:52px;box-shadow:0 -12px 27px #999;display:flex;align-items:center">
   <div style="display: flex;flex:1;height:24px;margin-left:20px">
      <div style="display:inline-block;width:24px;height:24px;border: 1px solid green;"><img style="width:100%;height:100%;border:0" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mP8/x8AAwMCAO+ip1sAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="Logo"></div>
      <h1 style="display:inline-block;margin:0;text-transform:uppercase;font-family:Raleway, serif;font-weight:900;font-size:18px;height:24px;border: 1px solid red;">MyLogo</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wPYOed

Comment: Damn, so easy! Didn't see that mistake. Thanks a lot!